# Reading QTableView row contents with the same order as are seen NOT stored

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qtableview

We have a QTableView which are filled with some arbitrary data. User can reorder rows of the table by make verticalHeader moveable. Here is a sample code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHeaderView>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget base;
    QTableWidget* tablWid = new QTableWidget(&base);
    tablWid->verticalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
    tablWid->verticalHeader()->setDragEnabled(true);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Fill the model with some data
    tablWid->model()->insertColumn(0);
    tablWid->model()->insertRows(0,10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        tablWid->model()->setData(tablWid->model()->index(i, 0), "Item " + QString::number(i));
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    QPushButton* dumpButton = new QPushButton("Dump Model", &base);
    QObject::connect(dumpButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [tablWid]()->void {
        for (int j = 0; j < tablWid->model()->rowCount();++j){
            qDebug() << tablWid->model()->index(j, 0).data().toString();
        }
    });
    QVBoxLayout* baseLay = new QVBoxLayout(&base);
    baseLay->addWidget(tablWid);
    baseLay->addWidget(dumpButton);
    base.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

We want to read cell contents in the same order as are seen in the QTableView (as seen in the view NOT stored in the model). Currently by calling model->data() we access the cell contents as are stored in the model NOT as seen in the view (ordered are changed by vertical section moves).

How is it possible to read cell contents such this way?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood it correctly you want to reorder the columns by moving the headers and then want to know how the view looks like.
I believe ( 90% certain ) when you reorder the headers it does not trigger any change in the model! and then if you just start printing the data of the model you will only see the data in the order how it was initially before you swapper/reordered some column with the header.

But you can maintain your own little data structure maintaining the order of the headers and when you will reorder a header the slot `columnMoved()` will be invooked at that point of time you can utilize the method `columnViewportPosition` to figure out the positions of all the columns and update your small data structure storing the order of the columns.

So while printing the data you should always assume that headers are in the order as in your own data structure.

Hope that will do what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks, That's a way. But, I've thought there might be easiest ways also!

Comment: alternatively you can also perform a real swap on the model when based on the new order you computed by columnViewportPosition on columnMoved rather than maintaining a structure of your own!
However that will also trigger the model updates which you may not be interested in and should block them with QSignalBlocker while performing this kind of swap!

Post the easier way if you could find one ;)

Cheers!